# How can I remove the extra set of " " from html class?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add at fecthed variable string as a html class, but I'm getting an extra set of "".

```
    setInterval(function(){
        return function(){
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/showTable')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = data;
                document.getElementById("table").className = data;
            });
        };
    }(), 1000);
```

That gives me this class in the Inspector:

```
<p id="table" class=" "Green0" " >"Green0"</p>
```

How can I remove the extra set of " " ?

Comment: Sounds like your `showTable` endpoint is returning bad HTML. Fix it on *that* end, not on the client-side

Comment: Agree with @CertainPerformance, it should return a string without the quotes. In any case add a `console.log` in the second `.then` to see what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `replace()` function.
Here is your code:

```
setInterval(function(){
        return function(){
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/showTable')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                data = data.replace('"', '');
                data = data.replace('"', ''); //Do it twice.
                document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = data;
                document.getElementById("table").className = data;
            });
        };
    }(), 1000);
```

Comment: @Kresten ... "it does work for me (but actually I do not know/bother why)" should not be your criteria of acceptance. From all until now suggested approaches/solutions this one is the one I would not accept at all. If one does consider a `replace` based approach then rather Elman Huseynov's one. And before this I would even listen to Barmar and countercheck on his assumptions.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Sir, note that the comment section's main objective is to ask for more information or details and not to distinguish between users' answers. Second, I consider the `replace` based approach to make it simple. Because I noticed that many people hate regular expressions but this doesn't mean that Elman Huseynov's method is not working, but his method is shorter than mine. So right now the balance scales are equal.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from the question result from the API returns string  "Green0", which means that before add it to class you need to parse it and remove quotes from it and then add it to the table class by using classList method. Please try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
        return function(){
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/showTable')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = data;
                let class_name = data.replace(/"/g,"");
                document.getElementById("table").classList.add(class_name);
            });
        };
    }(), 1000);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the API is returning JSON, not plain text. You need to parse it.

```
setInterval(function(){
    return function(){
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/showTable')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = data;
            document.getElementById("table").className = data;
        });
    };
}(), 1000);
```